# GitHub REST API For Delete Branch

Tags: git, github

I've been reading the [GitHub API Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/branches) and searching around. It seem like there's no REST API for deleting a branch in GitHub? The closes thing I found is another post on [Github enterprise API delete branch after merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455942/github-enterprise-api-delete-branch-after-merge).

Is there a reason why that is? What is the proper way to delete a branch using REST API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Branches are references to a commit. The documentation you seek is called [Delete a reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#delete-a-reference).

Here is some more information on [Git references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).

Comment: So the proper way of deleted branch(es) are just deleting the reference?

Comment: I've not used it, but from the looks of the API, I'd say, yes. I'm guessing deleting a branch named "my-branch" would use DELETE with URL `.../refs/heads/my-branch`. I would push out some test branches and try it out. (Maybe even on a test repo if you're concerned about it.)

Comment: So I tried the delete and it does work, but on the GitHub interface itself, it still shows `<branch> had recent pushes <x> minutes ago`, feel like there are still some clean up, but i guess it should work for now, thanks for the help

Comment: @YTKme I'd try deleting a branch through the Web UI and see if that display shows differently. If yes, then I agree, there may be other cleanup and/or refreshing required before it acts identically. Feel free to update here, including updating this answer if you find out more steps are necessary.

Comment: yeah, i tried deleting from the web ui, and the messages go away, i'll have to experiment a little to see what other clean up is needed, will update if i find anything